# How to set width of scollbar overlay-y

Tags: javascript, css

HI I have a vertical scrollbar. because I have some icons. And if the icons are increasing. you can't see the bottom icons anymore. So I added a scrollbar. But now the scrollbar is pressing half of the icons. So the icons are not visible totally anymore.

so this I have as css:

```
#makelist {
  width: 250px;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  max-width: 300px;
  scrollbar-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -210px;
  background-color: #91c7e1;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow-y:overlay;
  height: 700px;
}
```

this is html:"

```
<div id="makelist">
            <ul id="makelistul"></ul>
        </div>
```

So my question is: How to make the width of the scrollbar wider?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide a scrollbar:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

But it's not the best practice, you should give a hint to a user that it's scrollable element by adding shadows or arrows at the ends of the element

For cross-browser compatibility add also:

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

Comment: Thank you. But this doesnt change anything.

Comment: I don;t see the scrollbar.